# Conexion a Twitter

Tags: java, twitter-api

me gustaria saber en que falla el codigo, me dice que "Cannot instantiate the type Twitter" donde instancio un objeto Twitter, Trabajo con la libreria twitter4j.

```
import java.util.List;    
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
public class twitterMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {
            Twitter twitter = new Twitter("XXXXXXX","YYYYYYYY");
          } catch (TwitterException ex) {             
            System.out.println("Error: "+ex.getMessage());   
          }    

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para instanciar debe ser

```
           try {
           //Twitter twitter = new Twitter("XXXXXXX","YYYYYYYY");
           Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
           twitter.setOAuthConsumer("[consumer key]", "[consumer secret]");

          } catch (TwitterException ex) {             
            System.out.println("Error: "+ex.getMessage());   
          }
```

Puedes verlo en la documentación de Twitter4j:
http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html